# CXF client unmarshalling error

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-rs, jaxb2

I have a CXF JAX-RS client which calls a service to fetch a XML result. The configuration is as follows :

```
<jaxrs:client id="pSClient"
        address="${F_S_P_URL}"
        serviceClass="com.abc.FSService"
        inheritHeaders="true"> 
        <jaxrs:headers>
           <entry key="Accept" value="application/xml"/>
       </jaxrs:headers>
        <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
        </jaxrs:inInterceptors>

        <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
        </jaxrs:outInterceptors>

        <!-- <jaxrs:outFaultInterceptors> <bean class="com.mmt.cms.rest.client.filters.ResponseTimeClientLogger" 
            /> </jaxrs:outFaultInterceptors> -->
    </jaxrs:client>
```

The problem is that the XML i am receiving has quote(") within one of the attributes which causes unmarshalling error like this :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 231; columnNumber: 44; Element type "RoomType" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".]
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:576)
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:497)
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:480)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.readFromSource(MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.java:116)
        ... 54 more
```

I don't have the option of modifying service. Service is receiving this invalid value from some other source and send it to the client but the client is not.

Any help regarding this would be helpful. Could I make unmarshalling more lenient or some thing?

Comment: You're receiving invalid XML. Not much to be done about that

Comment: @kolossus : Can I somehow edit that field using text processing.

Comment: Not unless you intervene at the application server level, maybe with a valve or something. Don't do this. Why would you want to? You're getting malformed content and you want to massage it? why?